# Organize the custom taxonomy/post type for Tv shows/programs Wordpress sites

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I wondering to handle these requirement in wp with custom taxonomy/post type.
Here is the some basic requirement I sketch and need to show.

```
Online Talk Show

 Chanel 1

 TS1 Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)
 TS2 Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)
 TS3 Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)
 .
 .
 .
 TS(n) Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)

 Chanel 2

 TS1 Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)
 .
 .
 .
 TS(n) Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)
 .
 .
 .

 Chanel (n)

Online Dramas

Chanel 1

D1 Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)
.
.
.
D(n) Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)

Chanel 2

D1 Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)
.
.
.
D(n) Episode1 Episode2 Episode3 ... Episode(n)
.
.
.

Chanel (n)
```

For the solution of these requirement I have create wp custom post type/taxonomy.

1. Custom post Type:

   - Talk Show slug:talk-show
   - Dramas    slug:drama
2. Custom Taxonomy:

   - Chanel
   - Talk Show List
   - Dramas List

Chanel Taxonomy connect to both *post type* ,  *Talk Show List* only connected to **Talk Show** and *Dramas List* only connected to **Dramas**
So, new post behave as new episode for both post type.
In New Episode will choose channel and respect post type list for both post type.
And The Code:

```
add_action( 'init', '_addition_init' );

function _addition_init(){
$drama_labels = array(
     'name'               => _x( 'Dramas Episode', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'singular_name'      => _x( 'Drama Online', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'menu_name'          => _x( 'Dramas Online', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Drama', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'add_new'            => _x( 'Add Drama Episode', 'dramas', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Drama Episode', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'new_item'           => __( 'New Drama Episode', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Drama Episode', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'view_item'          => __( 'View Drama Episode', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'all_items'          => __( 'All Drama Episodes', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'search_items'       => __( 'Search Drama Episodes', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Drama Episodes:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'not_found'          => __( 'No Drama(s) found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
     'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Drama(s) found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
 );

$drama_args = array(
 'labels'             => $drama_labels,
 'public'             => true,
 'publicly_queryable' => true,
 'show_ui'            => true,
 'show_in_menu'       => true,
 'query_var'          => true,
 'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'dramas-online' ),
 'capability_type'    => 'post',
 'has_archive'        => true,
 'hierarchical'       => false,
 'menu_position'      => null,
 'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' )
 );
register_post_type( 'dramas-online', $drama_args );
/**
* Custom Post Type: Talk Shows
*/

$talk_show_labels = array(
   'name'               => _x( 'Talk Show', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'singular_name'      => _x( 'Talk Show', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'menu_name'          => _x( 'Talk Show', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Talk Show', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'add_new'            => _x( 'Add Talk Show Episode', 'dramas', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Talk Show Episode', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'new_item'           => __( 'New Talk Show Episode', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Talk Show Episode', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'view_item'          => __( 'View Talk Show Episode', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'all_items'          => __( 'All Talk Show Episodes', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'search_items'       => __( 'Search Talk Show Episodes', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Talk Show Episodes:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'not_found'          => __( 'No Talk Show(s) found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
   'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No talk Show(s) found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
   );

$talk_show_args = array(
   'labels'             => $talk_show_labels,
   'public'             => true,
   'publicly_queryable' => true,
   'show_ui'            => true,
   'show_in_menu'       => true,
   'query_var'          => true,
   'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'talk-shows' ),
   'capability_type'    => 'post',
   'has_archive'        => true,
   'hierarchical'       => false,
   'menu_position'      => null,
   'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' )
   );

register_post_type( 'talk-shows', $talk_show_args );
/*
* Custom Category: Tv Chanels
*/ 
 $category_chanels_labels = array(
     'name'              => _x( 'Chanels', 'taxonomy general name' ),
     'singular_name'     => _x( 'Chanel', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
     'search_items'      => __( 'Search Chanels' ),
     'all_items'         => __( 'All Chanels' ),
     'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Chanel' ),
     'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Chanel:' ),
     'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Chanel' ),
     'update_item'       => __( 'Update Chanel' ),
     'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Chanel' ),
     'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Chanel' ),
     'menu_name'         => __( 'Chanels' ),
 );

 $category_chanels_args = array(
     'hierarchical'      => true,
     'labels'            => $category_chanels_labels,
     'show_ui'           => true,
     'show_admin_column' => true,
     'query_var'         => true,
     'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'chanel' ),
 );

 register_taxonomy( 'chanels', array( 'talk-shows', 'dramas-online'), $category_chanels_args );
/*
* Custom Category: Dramas List
*/ 
 $category_drama_labels = array(
     'name'              => _x( 'Drama', 'taxonomy general name' ),
     'singular_name'     => _x( 'Drama', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
     'search_items'      => __( 'Search Drama' ),
     'all_items'         => __( 'All Drama' ),
     'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Drama' ),
     'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Drama:' ),
     'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Drama' ),
     'update_item'       => __( 'Update Drama' ),
     'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Drama' ),
     'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Drama' ),
     'menu_name'         => __( 'Drama List' ),
 );

 $category_drama_args = array(
     'hierarchical'      => true,
     'labels'            => $category_drama_labels,
     'show_ui'           => true,
     'show_admin_column' => true,
     'query_var'         => true,
     'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'drama' ),
 );

 register_taxonomy( 'drama', array('dramas-online'), $category_drama_args );
 // Programas
 $category_programs_labels = array(
   'name'              => _x( 'Programs', 'taxonomy general name' ),
   'singular_name'     => _x( 'Program', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
   'search_items'      => __( 'Search Program' ),
   'all_items'         => __( 'All Programs' ),
   'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Program' ),
   'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Program:' ),
   'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Program' ),
   'update_item'       => __( 'Update Program' ),
   'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Program' ),
   'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Program' ),
   'menu_name'         => __( 'Programs' ),
   );

 $category_programs_args = array(
   'hierarchical'      => true,
   'labels'            => $category_programs_labels,
   'show_ui'           => true,
   'show_admin_column' => true,
   'query_var'         => true,
   'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'program' ),
   );

 register_taxonomy( 'program', array('talk-shows'), $category_programs_args );
}
```

And finally facing issues to show dramas and talk show according to channels with each episode as mentioned and show pattern earlier.

Comment: What is your question, is there some specific code you are having trouble with?

Comment: I'm facing problem to handle this requirement with efficient way...I have draw some code, but didn't get best way to show this stuff on front end.

Comment: If you have idea to handle this requirement with wp, so share with us

Comment: This site is about fixing specific programming problems, not for writing code for you, or for giving you opinions on how to structure your code. Additionally you're speaking on very broad terms and it's hard to give you a clear and concise answer without a specific problem. Check out the pages on [asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [what kind of questions to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to learn about what kind of questions are appropriate for SO.